# How to add a new check box in cart price rule form in magento 2.3 backend?

Tags: magento2.3

How to add a new check box in cart price rule form in magento 2.3 backend? and based on the value how to perform custom actions

Comment: Please check this post if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215206/how-to-add-a-new-field-in-cart-price-rule-form-in-magento-2-backend/215217

Comment: Thank you Bhaumik . This Post helped me to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

$installer = $setup;
         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.5.1', '<')) {

```
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('salesrule'),
            'shipping_custom_field',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'length' => 1,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'comment' => 'shipping_custom_field'
            ]
        );
    }
     $installer->endSetup();
```

shipping_custom_field
                
            
            
                number
                Calculate Shipping Amount
                true
                shipping_custom_field
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                0
                                No
                            
                            
                                1
                                Yes